# Javascript Regular Expression for rgb values

Tags: javascript, regex, rgb

I'm trying to get the individual values of a rgb string. I've been getting close, but I'm just   hitting a wall. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
var color = rgb(255, 85, 120);

/// My Regex ///
var rRegex = /^rgb\(\d{3}/;  // Which actually gives me an array of two strings...ugh
var gRegex = ;
var bRegex = ;

var r = color.match(rRegex);
var g = color.match(gRegex);
var b = color.match(bRegex);
```

I'm just looking to have:

```
/// // I think I can pull these off by Starts With and Ends With anchors... ///
r = 'From "(" to "," ';
g = 'From "," to "," ';
b = 'From "," to ")" ';
```

I'm trying to make also make it so that the regex can take either 1, 2, or 3 numbers, as the values go from 0 - 255. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `/^rgb\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)$/`

Comment: This one seemed to work the best, thanks, Orbling!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is some example code that should do approximately what you need or set you in the right direction:

```
var color = 'rgb(255, 15, 120)';
var matchColors = /rgb\((\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3})\)/;
var match = matchColors.exec(color);
if (match !== null) {
    document.write('Red: ' + match[1] + ' Green: ' + match[2] + ' Blue: ' + match[3]);
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xonev/dRk8d/

Comment: Never ceases to amaze. Thanks, Steven, it worked perfectly! And thanks for everyone else's insanely fast responses as well.

Comment: I used this code, but I used Orbling's regex. For some reason it worked better. I'm not sure why though. Sometimes your regex would not work, producing a null. Still amazing help, thank you!

Comment: The differences between my regex and Orbling's are: Orbling's requires that the color definition be the only thing in the string (he has anchor tags that match the beginning and end of the string), Orbling's allows numbers with more than 3 digits (mine only allows 1, 2, or 3 digits), and Orbling's does not allow spaces.  Otherwise they are very similar.  arc's regex may actually be the most general - it allows any (or no) whitespace between the individual numbers, commas, etc.

Comment: @Strongwings: What regex you need for your situation depends on the variability of what is likely to come in.  My regex assumed that it would very religiously be a string of the form `"rgb(#,#,#)"`, no spaces, no gaps, just three numbers wrapped in the `rgb(...)` bit.  Steven's version requires spaces after each comma and no more than 3 digits, also, it allows other content in the string.  I suspect the spaces are the issue with your input and his regex.  arc's version allows for any level of spacing between points.  Just pick the simplest one to suit the variability of your situation.

Comment: Works, except values like rgb(999, 999, 999) will pass the test. If you're worried about errors with these values, I'd double check the values you receive.

Answer (score 12):

I have come up with this `"^(rgb)?\(?([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\W+)([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\W+(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\)?)$"` which can validate a whole heap of string variations including:

- rgb(255,255,255)
- rgb(255, 255, 255) rgb(0/0/0)
- rgb(50-50-50)
- rgb(0 - 0 - 0)
- rgb(255,0-50)
- rgb(0, 255 255)
- rgb( 0 0 0 )
- 255,255,255
- 255, 255, 0
- (0, 0, 30)
- (255 - 255 - 255)
- rgb0 0 0
- rgb255 - 0/255

Comment: This is perfect! How would you add RGB %s to it as well?

Comment: care to explain the REGEX?

Answer (score 9):

Try this regex:

```
/rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)$/
```

It will capture the r value into $1, the g value into $2, and the b value into $3

Answer (score 9):

Given a string is valid rgb, parsing numbers out it is a matter of matching digits:

```
"rgb(12, 34, 56)".match(/\d+/g); // ["12", "34", "56"]
```

Comment: @yckart: It's a global regexp, so you need to `.exec` multiple times. Each run you'll obtain a next match. In this case: `var regexp = /\d+/g; var r = regexp.exec(str)[0]; var g = regexp.exec(str)[0]; var b = regexp.exec(str)[0];`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. A regex within the range 0 - 255.

```
rgb\((( *0*([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) *),){2}( *0*([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) *)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dyR5Du_ciXVr45vV)

Answer (score 1):

I use this one: `rgb\(\s*(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,?){3}\)$`

- prefix is `rgb`
- at the end we have `{3}` it means we will checks conditions from below 3 times
- `\d{1,2}` if value inside have only 1 or 2 symbols - check if there are digits
- `1\d\d` if value inside have 3 digits and first one is equals to `1`
  and rest of them are digits
- `2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5])` if value inside have 3 digits and first one is equals to `2` then

  - `?:[0-4]\d` if second symbol is in range of `0-4` the third one should any digit
  - `5[0-5]` if second symbol is equals to `5` then third symbol should be digit from range `0-5`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\\d{1,2}|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-5][0-5]);(\\d{1,2}|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-5][0-5]);(\\d{1,2}|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-5][0-5])$
```

format `x;x;x` where `x` is a number between `0` (included) and `255` (included)

Comment: This wouldn't allow 249 or similar values. 250 is allowed and 255, but not 2[0-5]{6,7,8,9}.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rgb(value) {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }

  return value.match(new RegExp('^rgb\\((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]), ?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]), ?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9])\\)$')) !== null;
}

function rgba(value) {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }

  return value.match(new RegExp('^rgba\\((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]), ?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]), ?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]), ?(1|0|0\.[0-9]+)\\)$')) !== null;
}
```

Examples:

```
'rgb(255,255,255)' // true
'rgb(255, 255,255)' // true
'rgb(255, 255, 255)' // true
'rgb(0,0,0)' // true
'rgb(255,255,255)' // true
'rgb(256,255,255)' // false, min: 0, max: 255
'rgb(01,1,1)' // false, zero is not accepted on the left, except when the value was exactly 0 (here 0 != 00)
```

Comment: You have to explain why you create such a complex regexp. Beside that `rgb(01,1,1)` and `rgb(256,255,255)` are valid syntax according to the css standard.

Comment: In the examples I found it bothered me to accept any character with \ d {1,3} (001 or 999). I limited the first case because the zeros are unnecessary, and I limited the second because I only need to go up to 255 currently. My code is just a more restrictive version.

Comment: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' // true <- this return false. your regex does not check for spaces

Answer (score 0):

Typescript solution:

```
interface RGB {
  r: number,
  g: number,
  b: number
}

const str2rgb = (color: string): RGB => {
  const rgbSubset = color
    .split('(')
    .pop()
    ?.split(')')
    .shift()
    ?.split(',')
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map(Number);

  if (rgbSubset && rgbSubset.length === 3) {
    const [r, g, b] = rgbSubset;
    return {r, g, b};
  }

  throw new Error(`Invalid color = ${color}`);
};
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only, see [answer]. Always remember that you are not only answering the OP, but also to any future readers (especially when answering an 8 year old question), thus [edit] the post to contain some explanation as to **why** this works.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to #HHHHHH - ignoring the transparency bit

```js
const numToHex = c => (+c).toString(16).padStart(2,"0").toUpperCase();

const rgbToHex = (rgb) => {
  const [r, g, b] = rgb.split(",");
  return "#" + numToHex(r) + numToHex(g) + numToHex(b)
};

const getRgb = sel => window
  .getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(sel), null)
  .getPropertyValue('background-color')
  .match(/(\d+, \d+, \d+)/)[1]; // assuming there will be a set

console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp1")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp2")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp3")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp4")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp5")));
```

```css
.nhcp4 {
  background-color: teal
}

.nhcp5 {
  background-color: rgba(211, 0, 211, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="nhcp1" style="background-color:red">Div 1</div>
<div class="nhcp2" style="background-color:blue">Div 2</div>
<div class="nhcp3" style="background-color:green">Div 3</div>
<div class="nhcp4">Div 4</div>
<div class="nhcp5">Div 5</div>
```