# Validating RGB String using regex in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, validation

I've been trying to figure out the best way to validate a user entry which is a string with comma separated RGB values. It should only allow strings with no whitespaces and in formats such as these (1,12,123; 225,225,2; 32,42,241...).

I've never used Regex before, but i'm guessing it would be the best solution? I've been playing around on [RegexPal](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=116826) and have gotten this string working:

`(#([\da-f]{3}){1,2}(\d{1,3}%?,\s?){3}(1|0?\.\d+)\)|\d{1,3}%?(,\s?\d{1,3}%?){2})`

However, not having much luck using it in Swift. I get the error "Invalid escape sequence in literal".

Would appreciate any help with using that regex in Swift, or if there's a better regex string/solution to validating the entry. Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with Swift, but you likely need to escape the backslash if you define the regex as a string, so for `[\da-f]` you might need `"[\\da-f]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hashtag before the first double quote and after the last double quote in Swift to avoid having to manually add a backslash before any special character. Regarding the regex you are using it would allow the user to enter values above the 255 limit.

The regex below adapted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864536/2303865) would limit the values from 0-255 and would allow the user enter 1 or more rgb values followed by `";"` or `"; "`

```
#"^\((((([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])),){2}(([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))(;|; )?){1,}\)$"#
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isValidRGB: Bool { range(of: #"^\((((([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])),){2}(([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))(;|; )?){1,}\)$"#,
                                 options: .regularExpression) != nil }
}
```

---

```
"(200,55,1)".isValidRGB // true
"(10,99,255; 0,0,10)".isValidRGB // true
"(2,2,2;)".isValidRGB // true
"(2,2,2;2)".isValidRGB // false
"(2,2,2;2,2)".isValidRGB // false
"(2,2,254;0,0,0)".isValidRGB // true
"(2,2,256;0,0,0)".isValidRGB // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the Swift code where you define the RegEx to your question.

The other poster likely has identified the problem. (@manzarhaq, you should really post your reply as an answer so the OP can accept it.)

The backslash is a special character in Swift strings. It tells the compiler that the character next is a special character. If you want a literal backslash, you need 2 backslashes in a row. So your regEx string might look like this:

```
let regExStrin = "(#([\\da-f]{3}){1,2}(\\d{1,3}%?,\\s?){3}(1|0?\\.\\d+)\\)|\\d{1,3}%?(,\\s?\\d{1,3}%?){2})"
```

Note that using backslashes this way is common to most languages that derive, even loosely, from C. Swift does have some C in its ancestry.

In many C-like languages, `\n` is a newline character, `\t` is a tab character, `\f` is a form-feed, `\"` is a quotation mark, and `\\` is a literal backslash.

(I don't think the `\f` form feed character is defined in Swift. That harks back to the days of ASCII driven serial printers.)