# Regex for splitting rgb values from a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex for splitting `rgb` values from a given string below are the test cases which should pass the check.

```
0 0 0
0,0,0
0, 0, 0
rgb(0 0 0)
rgb(0,0,0)
rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

The regex I created to solve this problem.

```js
const regex = /(^[\d\s,]+)|(^rgb\([0-9\s,]+\))/gi
```

but there are certain criteria's :

1. `r`,`g`,`b` values should between `[0-255]`.
2. 000 or 255255255 should not return `true`.
3. regex should not pass any other `string` other than mentioned above.

```js
const REGEX = /(^[\d\s,]+)|(^rgb\([0-9\s,]+\))/gi

const TEST_CASES = [
  '0 0 0',
  '0,0,0',
  '0, 0, 0',
  'rgb(0 0 0)',
  'rgb(0,0,0)',
  'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
]

for (let i = 0; i < TEST_CASES.length; i++) {
  console.log(REGEX.test(TEST_CASES[i]))
}
```

As you can see the regex returning false for some test cases.

Comment: Sometimes pure-regex isn't the way to go. Sometimes, it's [awful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029238/4935162). How about utilizing simple code to "normalize" the data first?

Comment: @Yarin_007  I agree but this regex is super long and I didn't understand a bit what it is easy doing rather than it is passing the test cases. I see you updated the link again for now I just want the regex for passing only the above test cases no more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the integers to the 0-255 range, the regex will have to test specific digit sequences. As you need this *three* times, you could probably benefit from creating your regex dynamically, and capture each number in a separate capture group.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
const byte = String.raw`(2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]\d)|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)`;
const tuple = String.raw`${byte}[ ,][ ]*${byte}[ ,][ ]*${byte}`;
const regex = RegExp(String.raw`^(?:${tuple}|rgb\(${tuple}\))$`);

const tests = [
  '0 0 255',
  '0,128,0',
  '99, 0, 0',
  'rgb(0 250 100)',
  'rgb(0,8,9)',
  'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
// Negative tests
  '155255255',
  '1,1,1)',
  'rgb(2,2,2',
  '3,3,3,',
  '256,4,4',
  '5,260,5',
  '6,,',
];

for (let s of tests) {
  let arr = s.match(regex);
  if (arr) {
    const [r, g, b] = arr.slice(1).filter(Boolean).map(Number);
    console.log(r, g, b);
  } else console.log("no match");
}
```

It is important, **not** to use the `g` flag with the `test` method here, as then it uses and modifies the *state* of the regex. This is not what you want here.

Using `match` we get the whole match and each capture group in an array. As there are 6 capture groups, the array has 7 entries. Entries 1,2,3 are filled when the input does not have "rgb", while entries 4,5,6 are filled when the input has "rgb". With `.slice(1)` we discard entry 0 (the full match); with `filter(Boolean)` we retain the filled three entries, and with `map(Number)` we convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the `for of`

Comment: You mean the `for..of` syntax or the what happens inside the loop?

Comment: yeah exactly!!! because I am trying to capture `rgb` values as `const [r, g, b] = ...`

Comment: OK, I edited the script to destructure like that, and added explanation of the array manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Man!!  Now It is quite clear what is happening inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is to valid numbers from 0 to 255 : `^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`

```js
const REGEX = /^(?:(?:rgb\())?(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:,?\s?)){3}\)?$/i

const TEST_CASES = [
  '0 0 0',
  '0,0,0',
  '0, 0, 0',
  'rgb(0 0 0)',
  'rgb(0,0,0)',
  'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
]

for (let i = 0; i < TEST_CASES.length; i++) {
  console.log(REGEX.test(TEST_CASES[i]))
}
```

[Link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xamhWs/1)